# .NET5 Windows Authentification Prompt

Tags: iis, .net-core, windows-authentication

So I have developed an API with Windows Authentification. When I ran the project with Visual's Studio IIS Express - endpoint's secured with:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

In services I have registered:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

get's the current Windows user, which I can access through HttpContextAccessor.

After I have published the app to Windows Server (HTTPS enabled) with IIS 10 running when I am trying to access protected endpoints I just get Login Prompt and it doesn't matter what I enter in it, it goes away only if I cancel.

My Site settings in Windows IIS Server, Windows Auth uses Negotiate Provider:
[image: App authentification settings]
Application pool settings:
[image: Application pool in which app resides settings:]

Is there anything I can do to fix this? If this post lacks some other information, please, let me know, I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

When you enable anonymous authentication and authentication at the same time, iis will use anonymous authentication, so you need to disable anonymous authentication and try again.